# Set div to fill in the rest of the height dynamically?

Tags: html, css, svg, height

So. My code is something along the lines of

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="header" style="width:100%;min-height:0;display:block;background-color:#000">
        <img src="header_image.svg" />
    </div>
    <div id="content" style"display:block">
        Some content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an svg in the header that I have set so that it matches the width of the window and the height scales to preserve the svg. Then I have the rest of the page in another div. I would like it so that the page doesn't scroll and this content div fills to fit the rest of the window. The problem is that since the height of the header changes with the width of the window, I can't set the content div in pixels or percentage or anything concrete.

How can I set the height of the content div to change dynamically with the height of the header?

I don't know Javascript or JQuery (I know, I know - I should), but ideally the height of the content div would be set to be something like height:(height of viewport)-(height of header), but I haven't a clue how to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you don't have to use a script for that.
and also: I recommend you to separate your styling from your markup.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="header_image.svg" alt="the img is empty"/>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Some content</div>
</div>
```

add this to your **CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* this is the big trick*/
#wrapper:before {
    content:'';
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#header {
    background-color:#000;
}
#content {
    background-color: gray;
}
/* this is the big trick*/
#content:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/HwYYw/3/)

*Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, FF, Chrome.

1. didn't use absolute positioning
2. didn't use Script (Pure CSS solution)
3. fluid layout
4. cross-browser

**Explanation:**
with pseudo element, I'm creating a floating element (without content or width, so he's invisible)
that has 100% of the container height.

and with another pseudo element I'm creating a div just after the `content` div. (also without content, so he's also invisible)  that has the clear attribute. so he has to be below the floated one I've created earlier. making the `content` to go all the way down.

Comment: Black magic, never seen this before :) Please explain the "big trick", I am curious how that works!

Comment: Hmmm... I think I have made all the changes as you have, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I would really love to have this work, it's such an elegant solution.
I too have no idea how it works like @opatut.

The site is [tuckerchapin.com](http://tuckerchapin.com)

Comment: BTW: the script I've add, is not part of the solution. its just to show you that this works with dynamic data.

Comment: This works when I created a blank html and css file from scratch to test it out. So thank you for the solution, but I have yet to get it functioning with my existing content. Something is probably overriding it.

Comment: So post the entire HTML/CSS. and we'll try to find the problem. [better in a fiddle]

Comment: I have just realized that I put your "content" rather than my "container", but even when I fixed this, it doesn't work.

Comment: You were missing the html (from my first CSS rule). and the content thing (remove your styling for your old container) check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/5XAqx/4/) [dont forget to remove the gray background]

Comment: also, in your fiddle I saw that you mis-close your `link`s tags.

Comment: Did you want all those img's to be 100% heigt? you've puted them in `a` tags and didn't give them 1005 height.

Comment: so.. more black magic. but look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5XAqx/5/) I changed your markup to achieve this.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you. Thank you so much for that.
Is there any way I could give you proper credit for your help?

Comment: Emm, just remember to help someone else if you can.. And.. Mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: It seems like having `overflow: hidden` on the `content` screws this up. Any idea why?

Comment: @ido the `overflow:hidden;` causes the div to really compute its space. if you want to apply `overflow:hidden;`to the content, just add another layer (its a little bit tricky) [**here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HwYYw/122/)

Comment: Can you tell me if I can use similar solution if the flexible div getting the rest of the page is placed not last but first or somewhere in the middle? I was trying to do the same with the flexible one being before the fixed one but I couldn't.

Comment: @German yes. it can be done, but it's a little harder. but since this post, 'flexbox' got a better browser support and it make life a lot easier. you should use flexbox. see this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: saved my life. I'm would not say it is "an elegant solution" but it works great in actual conditions (lack of support of flex-box). Unfortunately it is incompatible with bootstrap and may be other css frameworks.

Comment: this will help to clear the top offset but is it possible to have the content height to be the remaining window height, 'coz here header also scrolls when i scroll down

Comment: @AravindReddy now that we have `flex`, we don't need this tricks anymore.

Comment: @avrahamcool yeah i know that but i have a table that should use the remaining height of window. I think for table we can't use flexbox

Comment: @AravindReddy why not?