# make div's height the rest of the page on responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

on my responsive design, i want a footer stick to the bottom and the content to fill up the rest of the page.
http://jsfiddle.net/rzjfhggu/1/

at this example, the header will always be 70px height, but the content and the footer are responsive so i can't know their height. 
i tried making the footer absolute with bottom: 0 and the content also absolute with top 70px and bottom 0, but on small devices the footer go on top of the content and hides it.

```css
.wrapper,
.header,
.content,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 70px;
  background: orange;
}
.footer {
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

any more ideas?
thanks.

Comment: Can you make the footer fixed height?

Comment: This may help you [Set div to fill in the rest of the height dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807145/set-div-to-fill-in-the-rest-of-the-height-dynamically).

Comment: you have to fix `position:fixed` for footer

Answer (score 0):

here is code i update in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rzjfhggu/2/

**HTML**

```css
.wrapper,
.header,
.content,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 70px;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  background: lightblue;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you've set a height to the footer. OP has said it has a variable height :(

Answer (score 0):

in case you don't know the size of your footer(as you said in the question) below code will calculate the footer height dynamically and then it will set the content height accordingly

```js
var pageheight = $(window).height();
var restheight = $('.header').height() + $('.footer').height();
$('.content').height(pageheight - restheight);
```

```css
 body
 {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 }

.wrapper,
.header,
.content,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 70px;
  background: orange;
}
.footer {
  background: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So many options, let's discuss one:
For this I am assuming you are the one determining the size of your footer and header items, meaning you know what size they are.

Changing a little to your html:

**HTML**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 70px 0 70px 0;
}
.inner_content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner_content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

the thing you change is the top and bottom padding of your content element, the top padding should be the same as your header height, and the bottom padding should be the same as your footer height. Providing that the sizes are rendered correctly, you can now also add some content to your inner_content, that can be scrolled, but will never be obscured by the header or footer.

Comment: you've set a height to the footer. OP has said it has a variable height :(

Comment: yes, but magic never happens, how does the footer change height? I am simply assuming that somewhere the height is set, when a different screen size is measured. Even if it is done by javascript you can still change the height of the padding in the same script.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` helps you but if your content been long there will content will be scroll down and at the last footer show for example show jsfiddle demo.
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/16dnj852/)

```css
.content {
    height: 10px
}
.header{
    height: 70px;
    background: orange;
}
.content{
    background: yellow;
    height:100%;
}
.footer {
    background: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        CONTENT
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        blah
        blah
        blah
       
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```